# C: Read and write between parent and multiple child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, unistd.h

Say I have a function called `worker(int in, int out)` that performs some task based on the given `in` file descriptor and takes the result and writes it to `out`.

It might look something like:

```
while (read(in, buffer, some_max_length) > 0){
    // Do something with buffer
    .
    .
    write(out, some_other_info, some_size);
}
```

Say I also have a main process that spawns a variable amount of processes that might look something like:

```
// Assume I have done error checking.
array_of_write_pipes[n][2];
array_of_read_pipes[n][2]; // Assume these have already been populated.

while(there is a word from stdin){
    // Spawn n processes 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        n = fork();
        if(n == 0){
            write(array_of_read_pipes[i][1], some_data, some_max_length);
            worker(some_other_data, array_of_read_pipes[i][0], array_of_write_pipes[i][1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // Block of code waiting for all children to terminate.

    // Collect the results of each child process

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        while (read(array_of_write_pipes[i][0], buffer, some_max_length) > 0){
            // Do something with buffer
            .
            .

        } 
    }
}
```

At the moment, it seems to hang.

My end goal is to have the main process send the same word to each child process. Each child process then performs the task via `worker()`. Then, the child process sends its results back to the main process for further processing.

At this moment, I'm not even sure if I'm even remotely going in the right direction. 
I tried to keep this question as general as possible except for the parts dealing with piping. If I'm missing any information, please let me know. Just a disclaimer, this is a homework related problem and I do **not** want the full answer, just whether or not my thought process is correct. If not, what am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the sequence of read/write operations is not correct.

Comment: when calling `fork()` there are three kinds of returns, but the posted code is only checking the 'child' return.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        n = fork();`  this is modifying the value in `n` every time through the loop.  `n` will be -1 or 0 or some large number.  Suggest using a different variable (with a type of `pid_t`) for the returned value from `fork()`,  Suggest keeping an array of the values returned from `fork()` to make it easy to gather all the sub processes

Comment: The question is about a run time problem.  When asking about a run time problem, please post a [mcve] so we can help you correct the problem.

Comment: Regarding comment 1: What is the correct sequence of operations? 2: What would belong in the parent? 3: Got it, thanks.

Comment: You stated you do not want a full answer, so I just pointed out some problems, not how to fix them

Comment: Thanks, so other than the order of read and write, the rest should be correct?

Comment: Have your read all the comments?  Each one is about some problem in the posted code.  Just fixing the order of activities is only one of the problems.